# How to create NSData out of Hexdump string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledata, hexdump

I have an NSData of an image, now I want to append a few bytes to the NSData of the image, I have the bytes as the Hexdump string. I need to append this: `62706c69 73743030 23400000 00000000 00080000 00000000 01010000 00000000 00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00113200 0000e802 00007005 00000100 00000100 00009132 a4cb` to the end of the image NSData. I think I should create an NSData from the hexdump string, but i dont have a clue how i should do this

Does anyone know this?

Comment: You should know by now that you need to post your relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a NSData object now, lets call it `origData`, and a NSString, lets call it `str`. First, remove any spaces or extraneous characters from the string, so it's just pure hex. You could also check that the length is then even, if not it's poorly formed.

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:origData];
const char *ptr = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSUInteger len = [str length]/2;
while(len--) {
    char num[5] = (char[]){ '0', 'x', 0, 0, 0 };
    num[2] = *ptr++;
    num[3] = *ptr++;
    uint8_t n = (uint8_t)strtol(num, NULL, 0);

    [data appendBytes:&n length:1];
}
```

I've used this kind of code for years, YMMV.